# Player spawn moves at every death

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to build a house around the player spawn in Minecraft 1.51.

When I spawned the first time I marked the block underneath my feet and built a house around it so I am safe when I spawn at night.
The problem is that the spawn point moves everytime I die.

Why is that and how can I prevent it?

Comment: fwiw if you build a bed in a safe location and use it, that'll become your spawn from that point on so you don't have to build a house in a random location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the spawn in minecraft is in a zone of 20x20 area centered at the world spawn point.

however,the spawn change when you sleep in a bed. so just build a house and sleep in your bed.

Comment: Makes sense in singleplayer. But in multiplayer I'd just love to "protect" the spawn from creeps etc. without (!) using plugins. If noones got a good answer to this, I'll mark this as my answer in one or two hours.

Comment: @manticore Then die a bunch of times, find out the corners of your spawn, build a well-lit secure area around it and there you go. :)

Comment: This is also the reason why you (almost) never see mp server where you start off in a tiny house of 3 by 4 blocks.

Comment: Easier way to detect spawn area in multiplayer is to deop yourself and try to dig around. The spawn area is protected, so blocks will just respawn after being mined. Find the edges, op yourself, and build.

Comment: *The* spawn does not change when you sleep in a bed; *your* spawn does.